# How can I check all elements of array are in Textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write some validation as part of my page that makes sure if the textbox has some required text that it will disable the button if its not there.

I have this working perfectly using the following jQuery code:

```
 <script>
 $(document).on("ready", function () {
     $('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function () {
        var $required = $(this).next().val();
        var $image = $(this).parent().next().children('img');
        var $errors = $('img:visible').length;
        if (($(this).val().indexOf($required) == -1) && ($(this).val() != '')) {
            $image.show();
            $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $image.hide();
            //Manually subtract from error otherwise it doesnt subtract until the next focus change
            $errors--;
            if ($errors == 0)
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

The problem occurs when the textbox requires two values. They are stored in a hidden input as a comma seperated string. How do i check that both exist? They can be in there in any order as long as they are both there. I know I can use a .split(',') to get and array and test them but thats the part im stuck on.

I have tried using both .inArray() and .each() but just cannot get anywhere with it.

I tried to set up a fiddle but couldnt get it working.

Here is a cutdown version of the HTML as its an MVC project so most of this is being populated by the models etc.

**HTML**

```
  <table width="100%" border="1px solid">
    <tr>
        <th>Source Text</th>
        <th>Translation</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Some text here</td>
        <td><input type="Text"><input type="hidden" value="Some"></td>
        <td><img id="cross" src="../cross.png" class="jq-cross hid" alt="error" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Some text here</td>
        <td><input type="Text"><input type="hidden" value="Some,Here"></td>
        <td><img id="cross" src="" class="jq-cross hid" alt="error" /></td>
    </tr>
<tr><td colspan="3"><button id="submit" type="submit">Update Translations</button>  </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Any help you can give me would be most appreciated. Hopefully I have provided enough information here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A lot of your logic will be simplified if you just mark required input fields like `<input type="text" data-required>` (or even just `<input required>` in HTML 5) then using that for your event handler selector like `$('input[data-required]:text').on('blur', fn)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function to loop over your comma seperated string, something like:

```
function isTextInText(text, searchtext) {
    var arr = text.split(',');

    for(var i=0, len=arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (searchtext.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isTextInText("hello","hello there")); //true   
console.log(isTextInText("hello,there","hello there")); //true
console.log(isTextInText("hello,bye","hello there")); //false
```

Then your if logic could become:

```
if (isTextInText($required,$(this).val())
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/e7qkd/

Answer (score 2):

Just use For...In Statement:

```
for(x in $required)
{
    if($(this).val().indexOf($required[x]) !== -1)
    {
        // Code in case if text don't have required string
    }
}
```

Comment: He may need to split `$required` by a comma.

Comment: He already mentioned it. I just gave him an answer, how to check each element in this array in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not what i was looking for. I dont want to use a foor loop.

Comment: @Glibnes I wanted to use the inArray function ideally. The answer i chose used this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("ready", function () {
     $('input[type="text"]').on('blur', function () {
        var $required = $(this).next().val().split(','); // split values with comma
                                                         // and make array
        var $image = $(this).parent().next().children('img');
        var $errors = $('img:visible').length;
        var value = $.trim( this.value );           // get blur text field value

        // checking value with inArray()

        if ( $.inArray(value, $required) ) {
            $image.show();
            $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $image.hide();
            //Manually subtract from error otherwise it doesnt subtract until the next focus change
            $errors--;
            if ($errors == 0)
                $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but this doesnt work. The problem is that the required text is not the only text that can go in the text box and if i enter something other than the required text along with the required text then the test fails.